# How do you turn an Observable array of objects, into an Observable of the data inside that array of objects?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm getting this error:

> Type 'Observable<Country[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
> Type 'Country[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Country': name, tld, alpha2Code, alpha3Code, and 20 more.ts(2322

---

I think it's because the endpoint im reaching serves back an array with an object inside of it. Here's an example.

https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/peru

---

This is the code I can't get to work. It refuses to compile and gives me the error I posted above.

```
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  country$!: Observable<Country>
  countryBorders$!: Observable<Country[]>

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params) => {
      let countryName = params['country'];
      this.country$ = this.apiService.getCountryByName(countryName)
    });
    };
  }
```

---

The getCountryByName() method looks like this:

```
  getCountryByName(name: string) {
    return this.http
      .get<Country[]>(`${this.api}/name/${name}`)
  }
```

---

How do I get the "this.country$" variable/observable/subject (idk what it is technically), to hold the data thats inside the object thats inside of the array that's being returned by the HTTP request?

I thought I could map the values out of the array, but this doesn't work either:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params) => {
      let countryName = params['country'];
      this.country$ = this.apiService.getCountryByName(countryName).pipe(map(([info])=>return info)
    });
    };
  }
```

When I do that, I don't get the error but this template:

```
<div *ngIf="country$ | async as country">
  <h1>{{country$}}</h1>
</div>
```

renders

```
[object Object]
```

...like the h1 on the page literally just says "[object Object]"

---

What am I doing wrong? What combination of operators do I need to use to convert the 'Observable<Country[]>' into just 'Observable<Country' so I can render it inside an html template like this?

```
  <div>
    <p><strong>Native Name: </strong>{{ country$.name.nativeName }}</p> 
    <p><strong>Population: </strong>{{ country$.population | number : '0.0' }}</p> 
    <p><strong>Region: </strong>{{ country$.region }}</p> 
    <p><strong>Sub Region: </strong>{{ country$.subregion }}</p> 
    <p><strong>Capital: </strong>{{ country$.capital }}</p></div>
    <div> 
      <p><strong>Top Level Domain: </strong>{{ country$.tld }}</p> 
      <p><strong>Currencies: </strong>{{ country$.currencies }}</p> 
      <p><strong>Languages: </strong>{{ country$.languages }}</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

---

This is the interface in case it's relevant to the answer:

```
export interface Country {
  name: Name; //---
  tld: string[]; //---
  cca2: string;
  ccn3: string;
  cca3: string;
  cioc: string;
  independant: Boolean
  status: string;
  unMember: Boolean;
  currencies: Currency[]; //---
  idd: Idd;
  capital: string[]; //---
  altSpellings: string[];
  region: string;
  subregion: string; //---
  languages: any; //---
  translations: any;
  latlng: number[];
  landlocked: Boolean;
  borders: string[]; //---
  area: number;
  demonyms: any;
  flag: string;
  maps: Maps;
  population: number; //---
  gini: any;
  fifa: string;
  car: any;
  timezones: string[];
  continents: string[];
  flags: Flags;
  coatOfArms: COA;
  startOfWeek: string;
  capitalInfo: Capital;
  postalCode: Postal;
  // nativeName: string;
  // numericCode: string;
  // regionalBlocs: RegionalBloc[];
}
```

Comment: `pipe(map(...))` receive an array and return a (modyfied) array. so not help you. you wanna receive an array and retrun single object. try: `this.country$ = this.apiService.getCountryByName(countryName).pipe(([info])=>return info)`

Comment: @YosefTukachinsky I get the error ------ "Type 'Observable<Country[]>' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.ts(2488)" --------- What does that mean?

Comment: Ok Im sorry you did right with `pipe(map(..))`. just when you render you not access any property of a country, but trying to render the whole object. on render try fo `country$.name` (or whatever property you trying to access)

Comment: When using, `this.country$ = this.apiService.getCountryByName(countryName).pipe(map(([info])=>return info)`  the template gives me this error: "Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Observable<Country>'".........on EVERY SINGLE property. Even though I know they exist. So I don't think the "this.countries$" is actually storing the data from the map function correctly. Do I need to use the "of()" operator after the map to store the data as an observable or something like that?

Comment: I figured it out. I was returning it correctly with `this.country$ = this.apiService.getCountryByName(countryName).pipe(map(([info])=>return info)` but in the template I was using I was doing {{country$.name.common}}, when I needed to be using {{country.name.common}}. Stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a typing issue in your `getCountryByName` method. Instead of `.get<Country[]>`, it should be `.get<Country>`:

```js
getCountryByName(name: string) {
  return this.http
    .get<Country>(`${this.api}/name/${name}`)
}
```

Comment: but it's returning an array, so wouldn't I need the type to be "Country[]" so typescript doesn't get mad? If it WASN'T returning an array I would use "Country", right?

Comment: Ok, then you have to change `country$!: Observable<Country>` to be `country$!: Observable<Country[]>`, so it would be consistent with the type your `getCountryByName()` method returns.

Answer (score 0):

The RestCountries API returns the response with an array type. You can achieve with extract the first element of the array via `map` rxjs.

```js
getCountryByName(name: string): Observable<Country> {
  return this.http
    .get<Country[]>(`${this.api}/name/${name}`)
    .pipe(map((x) => x[0]));
}
```

The way you extract the properties from the `country$` Observable is incorrect. You should look for an `async` pipe as what you have achieved in the question.

```
<div *ngIf="country$ | async as country">
  <div>
    <p><strong>Native Name: </strong>{{ country.name.nativeName | json }}</p>
    <p>
      <strong>Population: </strong>{{ country.population | number: '0.0' }}
    </p>
    <p><strong>Region: </strong>{{ country.region }}</p>
    <p><strong>Sub Region: </strong>{{ country.subregion }}</p>
    <p><strong>Capital: </strong>{{ country.capital }}</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p><strong>Top Level Domain: </strong>{{ country.tld }}</p>
    <p><strong>Currencies: </strong>{{ country.currencies }}</p>
    <p><strong>Languages: </strong>{{ country.languages }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2qxjwi?file=src/app/details/details.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

This was the correct format:

```
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  country$!: Observable<Country>
  countryBorders$!: Observable<Country[]>

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params) => {
      let countryName = params['country'];
      this.country$ = this.apiService.getCountryByName(countryName).pipe(map(([info])=>{return info}))
    });
    };
  }
```

I was doing it right. But in the template use:

```
<div *ngIf="country$ | async as country">
  <h1>{{country.name.common}}</h1>
</div>
```

**NOT**

```
<div *ngIf="country$ | async as country">
  <h1>{{country$.name.common}}</h1>
</div>
```

---

dumb mistake